# Issues when using namespace in a launch file

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-control, namespace

I've created a workspace where I launch a panda robot with a custom controller `(CartesianImpedance_trajectory_controller)` from  https://github.com/matthias-mayr/Cartesian-Impedance-Controller and I'm having some issues when launching both to gazebo. The problem I'm facing is that whenever I launch the robot and the controller without grouping them into a namespace, the simulation works and everything is fine. If I group them into a namespace called /panda, the simulation launches with any error but is not working.

This is my main.launch:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

  <!-- Gazebo & GUI Configuration -->
  <arg name="debug" default="false"/>
  <arg name="gui" default="true"/>
  <arg name="paused" default="true"/>
  <arg name="world" default="$(find robot_ctrl)/world/worldTable.world"/>
  <arg name="iiwa_controllers" default="joint_state_controller CartesianImpedance_trajectory_controller"/>
  <arg name="panda_controllers"  default="CartesianImpedance_trajectory_controller" />
  <arg name="robot_name" default="iiwa" />
  <arg name="robot_state_frequency" default="100" />



   <!-- Robot Customization: PANDA -->
   <include file="$(find robot_ctrl)/launch/launch_panda.launch">
    <arg name="x" value="0.6"/>
    <arg name="y" value="0"/>
    <arg name="z" value="0.5"/>
    <arg name="roll" value="0"/>
    <arg name="pitch" value="0"/>
    <arg name="yaw" value="3.1415"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
   </include>
   

  
  <!-- Robot Customization: iiwa 
   <include file="$(find robot_ctrl)/launch/launch_iiwa.launch">
    <arg name="origin_xyz" default="'-0.6 0 0.5'"/> 
    <arg name="origin_rpy" default="'0 0 0'"/>
   </include> -->

   <!-- World launch -->
   <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(arg world)"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless"    default="false" />
   </include>
   
</launch>
```

this is my panda launch (with the group commented out):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 
 <launch>
 <!-- Robot Customization PANDA -->
  <arg name="robot"       default="panda"                doc="Which robot to spawn (one of {panda,fr3})" />
  <arg name="arm_id"      default="$(arg robot)" doc="Name of the robot to spawn" />
  <arg name="use_gripper" default="true"  doc="Should a franka hand be mounted on the flange?" />
  <arg name="x"           default="0.6"     doc="How far forward to place the base of the robot in [m]?" />
  <arg name="y"           default="0"     doc="How far leftwards to place the base of the robot in [m]?" />
  <arg name="z"           default="0.5"     doc="How far upwards to place the base of the robot in [m]?" />
  <arg name="roll"        default="0"     doc="How much to rotate the base of the robot around its X-axis in [rad]?" />
  <arg name="pitch"       default="0"     doc="How much to rotate the base of the robot around its Y-axis in [rad]?" />
  <arg name="yaw"         default="3.1415"     doc="How much to rotate the base of the robot around its Z-axis in [rad]?" />
  <arg name="xacro_args"  default=""      doc="Additional arguments to pass to panda.urdf.xacro" />
  <arg name="paused" default="true"/>
  <arg name="initial_joint_positions"

       default="-J $(arg arm_id)_joint1 0
                -J $(arg arm_id)_joint2 -0.785398163
                -J $(arg arm_id)_joint3 0
                -J $(arg arm_id)_joint4 -2.35619449
                -J $(arg arm_id)_joint5 0
                -J $(arg arm_id)_joint6 1.57079632679
                -J $(arg arm_id)_joint7 0.785398163397
                -J $(arg arm_id)_finger_joint1 0.001
                -J $(arg arm_id)_finger_joint2 0.001"
       />
       

    <arg name="panda_controllers"  default="/panda/CartesianImpedance_trajectory_controller" />
    
     <!-- Spawn required ROS controllers -->
     <node pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" name="Cartesian_controller_spawner" output="screen" args="$(arg panda_controllers) " respawn="false"/>
  
   <!-- <group ns="panda" >-->

      <rosparam file="$(find franka_gazebo)/config/franka_hw_sim.yaml" subst_value="true" />
      <rosparam file="$(find robot_ctrl)/config/panda_controller.yaml" subst_value="true"/>
      <rosparam file="$(find robot_ctrl)/config/controllerPanda.yaml" subst_value="true"/>
      
      <param name="m_ee" value="0.76" if="$(arg use_gripper)" />
      
      <param name="robot_description"
         command="xacro $(find franka_description)/robots/$(arg robot)/$(arg robot).urdf.xacro
                  gazebo:=true
                  hand:=$(arg use_gripper)
                  arm_id:=$(arg arm_id)
                  xyz:='$(arg x) $(arg y) $(arg z)'
                  rpy:='$(arg roll) $(arg pitch) $(arg yaw)'
                  $(arg xacro_args)">
      </param>

      <!-- Run a python script to send a service call to gazebo_ros to spawn a URDF robot -->
      <node name="urdf_spawner" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-param robot_description -urdf -model $(arg arm_id) $(arg initial_joint_positions) "/>
      

      <!-- Spawn required ROS controllers -->
      <node pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" name="$(arg arm_id)_gripper_spawner" if="$(arg use_gripper)" args="franka_gripper" respawn="false"/>
      
      <!-- Panda Controller-->
       <node pkg="controller_manager"
        type="spawner"
        name="panda_controller_spawner"
        respawn="false" output="screen"
        args="--wait-for initialized franka_state_controller "
       />
      
      <!-- Panda state publisher -->
      <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" />
      <node name="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher">
        <rosparam param="source_list">[franka_state_controller/joint_states, franka_gripper/joint_states] </rosparam>
        <param name="rate" value="30"/>
      </node>
      
    <!--</group>-->
      
</launch>
```

my yaml:

```
franka_state_controller:
  type: franka_control/FrankaStateController
  publish_rate: 50  # [Hz]
  arm_id: $(arg arm_id)
  joint_names:
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint1
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint2
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint3
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint4
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint5
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint6
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint7
    
CartesianImpedance_trajectory_controller:
  type: cartesian_impedance_controller/CartesianImpedanceController
  arm_id: $(arg arm_id)
  joints:
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint1
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint2
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint3
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint4
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint5
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint6
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint7
  end_effector: panda_hand_tcp            # Link to control arm in
  update_frequency: 500                 # Controller update frequency in Hz
  # Optional parameters - the mentioned values are the defaults
  dynamic_reconfigure: true             # Starts dynamic reconfigure server
  handle_trajectories: true             # Accept traj., e.g. from MoveIt
  robot_description: /robot_description # In case of a varying name
  wrench_ee_frame: panda_hand_tcp         # Default frame for wrench commands
  delta_tau_max: 1.0                    # Max. commanded torque diff between steps in Nm
  filtering:                            # Update existing values (0.0 1.0] per s
    nullspace_config: 0.1               # Nullspace configuration filtering
    pose: 0.1                           # Reference pose filtering
    stiffness: 0.1                      # Cartesian and nullspace stiffness
    wrench: 0.1                         # Commanded torque
  verbosity:
    verbose_print: false                # Enables additional prints
    state_msgs: false                   # Messages of controller state
    tf_frames: false                    # Extra tf frames

model_example_controller:
  type: franka_example_controllers/ModelExampleController
  arm_id: $(arg arm_id)

force_example_controller:
  type: franka_example_controllers/ForceExampleController
  arm_id: $(arg arm_id)
  joint_names:
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint1
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint2
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint3
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint4
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint5
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint6
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint7

cartesian_impedance_example_controller:
  type: franka_example_controllers/CartesianImpedanceExampleController
  arm_id: $(arg arm_id)
  joint_names:
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint1
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint2
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint3
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint4
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint5
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint6
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint7

effort_joint_trajectory_controller:
  type: effort_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
  joints:
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint1
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint2
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint3
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint4
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint5
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint6
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint7
  gains:
    $(arg arm_id)_joint1: { p: 600, d: 30, i: 0 }
    $(arg arm_id)_joint2: { p: 600, d: 30, i: 0 }
    $(arg arm_id)_joint3: { p: 600, d: 30, i: 0 }
    $(arg arm_id)_joint4: { p: 600, d: 30, i: 0 }
    $(arg arm_id)_joint5: { p: 250, d: 10, i: 0 }
    $(arg arm_id)_joint6: { p: 150, d: 10, i: 0 }
    $(arg arm_id)_joint7: { p: 50, d: 5, i: 0 }
  constraints:
    goal_time: 0.5
    $(arg arm_id)_joint1: { goal: 0.05 }
    $(arg arm_id)_joint2: { goal: 0.05 }
    $(arg arm_id)_joint3: { goal: 0.05 }
    $(arg arm_id)_joint4: { goal: 0.05 }
    $(arg arm_id)_joint5: { goal: 0.05 }
    $(arg arm_id)_joint6: { goal: 0.05 }
    $(arg arm_id)_joint7: { goal: 0.05 }

position_joint_trajectory_controller:
  type: position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
  joints:
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint1
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint2
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint3
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint4
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint5
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint6
    - $(arg arm_id)_joint7
  constraints:
    goal_time: 0.5
    $(arg arm_id)_joint1: { goal: 0.05}
    $(arg arm_id)_joint2: { goal: 0.05}
    $(arg arm_id)_joint3: { goal: 0.05}
    $(arg arm_id)_joint4: { goal: 0.05}
    $(arg arm_id)_joint5: { goal: 0.05}
    $(arg arm_id)_joint6: { goal: 0.05}
    $(arg arm_id)_joint7: { goal: 0.05}

joint_velocity_example_controller:
    type: franka_example_controllers/JointVelocityExampleController
    joint_names:
        - $(arg arm_id)_joint1
        - $(arg arm_id)_joint2
        - $(arg arm_id)_joint3
        - $(arg arm_id)_joint4
        - $(arg arm_id)_joint5
        - $(arg arm_id)_joint6
        - $(arg arm_id)_joint7

joint_position_example_controller:
    type: franka_example_controllers/JointPositionExampleController
    joint_names:
        - $(arg arm_id)_joint1
        - $(arg arm_id)_joint2
        - $(arg arm_id)_joint3
        - $(arg arm_id)_joint4
        - $(arg arm_id)_joint5
        - $(arg arm_id)_joint6
        - $(arg arm_id)_joint7
```

The difference between the graph is the following:
With Ns
[image]

without Ns:
[image]

And after launching, I tried to do a rostopic list. There is no difference between them further than the namespace /panda before the topics.

[image]

I dont understand why when launching without the namespace I do for example a `rostopic echo /CartesianImpedance_trajectory_controller/commanded_torques` and I can see all the information. But when I do the same when I have the namespace `rostopic echo /panda/CartesianImpedance_trajectory_controller/commanded_torques` there is no information published.

I'm missing something with the namespaces but I need them in order to add another robot and separate both in two different namespaces.

Thanks in advance and regards.